# Python open file occure syntax error

Tags: python

I use python open a file
eg:aicrobo@xty-K55VD:~$ f = open('/home/aicrobo/train.txt)
 bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're typing Python into the bash shell.  You can't do that.  You need to start Python first.

Comment: Thank you very much!I got it.

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggests, this is an error in your bash syntax, not in Python syntax. In order to run Python commands in your terminal, you need to first open an interactive interpreter by running the `python` command (or `ipython` if you have that installed).

If you wish to run Python code from the command line without opening an interpreter or writing your code in a script, you can call `python` with the `-c` argument.

```
aicrobo@xty-K55VD:~$ python -c "print 'hello, world.'"
```

However, in most cases you will be better off starting the Python interpreter:

```
aicrobo@xty-K55VD:~$ python
```

and running your commands from there.

```
>>> f = open('/home/aicrobo/train.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I got it.

Comment: @Xiaobai don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful for you :)